# Cannot read the property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot and I have an error that I don't understand in this code : pas

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "";

client.login(token)

client.on("message", async(message) => {
  let staffRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Staff");
  let staff = message.guild.member(message.author);

  if (message.author.id === "424974772959444993" || message.member.roles.has(staffRole.id)) {
      return;
  }

  var badWords = [
    'asd',
    'legionmods',
    'verga',
    'vrga',
    'nmms',
    'alv',
    'electromods',
    'remake'
  ];
  var words = message.content.toLowerCase().trim().match(/\w+|\s+|[^\s\w]+/g);
  var containsBadWord = words.some(word => {
    return badWords.includes(word);
  });

  if (containsBadWord) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      description: `Has dicho una palabra que no esta permitida en este servidor`
    }

    message.channel.send(`${prefix}tempmute ${message.author}`+" 5m palabra prohibida")
  }
});
```

This is an error I get :

```js
(node:4952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 
'roles' of null
at Client.client.on (C:\Users\Francisco\Desktop\role\app.js:8:33)
```

Could someone help me please ? 
I am not good in debugging errors.

Comment: If you are starting with Programming I would suggest you to format your code, so it's easier to look at, and easier to find errors.

Comment: Seems like the message is not sent in a guild, you should stop the code if you see that the message is a [DM channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel)

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild` is probably returning `null` because the message was sent in a dm conversation, not a guild.

You can avoid this problem by writing:

```js
if (message.channel.type !== 'text') return;
```

---

Also, a few [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) methods have changed a bit since `discord.js` v12+. You should replace:

```js
let staffRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Staff");
```

With:

```js
let staffRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Staff");
```

And replace:

```js
message.member.roles.has(staffRole.id)
```

With:

```js
message.member.roles.cache.has(staffRole.id)
```